# Female djinn offspring

Tags: dnd-5e, lore

So I'm thinking of playing a genasi whose mother is a djinn, but I'm trying to figure out if that's even possible. How would the genasi have come to be? Would the djinn give birth since it is female? Would that change the dynamic of their relationship since most djinn see their mortal offspring as accidents?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you seem to be answering your own question.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Are you asking about the origins of the genasi in 5e lore?

Comment: It seems like you have two questions in there, which makes it hard to tell what you are really asking. Could you please [edit] your post to state clearly what **single** question you would like answered? (If you have multiple questions, you can post extra questions later in separate question posts.)